# Stuck on executing this function after 10 seconds of page load

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I created this function that checks for user's cookies and then shows a newsletter Popup. I need to load this after the user has spent 10 seconds navigating on the site. I've use window.setTimeout but it hasn't worked so far. The script works beautifully except for this 10 second delay execution. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter, 10000); {
theme.ModalNewsletter = function() 

  if ($.cookie('tada-cookies')) {
  } 
  else {
    var el = $('#newslettermodal');
    if (el.length) {
      $('#newslettermodal').removeClass("hide");
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: el
        },
        type: 'inline'
      });
    }

  }
  $.cookie('tada-cookies', 'true', { expires: 7});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment of calling setTimeout, theme.ModalNewsletter is still undefined so you are calling setTimeout with an argument of undefined, your function will never be called.

For instance, in this snippet, only A will be print into the console.

```
var obj = {
    a: function(){ console.log("A")}
};
window.setTimeout(obj.a, 1000);
window.setTimeout(obj.b, 1000);
obj.b = function(){ console.log("B")};
```

To fix your issue, you need to declare the property ModalNewsLetter before calling your setTimeout.